# Import error: No module named 'pandas.compat.numpy'

Tags: windows, python-3.x, anaconda

Just installed Anaconda for Windows and cannot fix the following problem when I am trying to import pandas:

```
import pandas as pd

**Traceback (most recent call last):**

File "C:\Users\Username\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python35\site-packages\IPython\core\interactiveshell.py", line 2885, in run_code
exec(code_obj, self.user_global_ns, self.user_ns)

File "", line 1, in
import pandas as pd

File "C:\Program Files (x86)\JetBrains\PyCharm 2016.1.3\helpers\pydev_pydev_bundle\pydev_import_hook.py", line 21, in do_import
module = self._system_import(name, args, *kwargs)

File "C:\Users\Username\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python35\site-packages\pandas__init__.py", line 22, in
from pandas.compat.numpy import *

File "C:\Program Files (x86)\JetBrains\PyCharm 2016.1.3\helpers\pydev_pydev_bundle\pydev_import_hook.py", line 21, in do_import
module = self._system_import(name, args, *kwargs)

ImportError: No module named 'pandas.compat.numpy'
```

Comment: Can you find the actual module on your system, for example, in the `C:\Users\Username\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python35\site-packages` directory (but might be elsewhere)?

Comment: Yes I can. The pandas file includes a compat file which includes a numpy file.

Answer (score 10):

This happened to me, and in my case it was due to an interrupted installation procedure. I did the following to fix it (although if some underlying problem still persists, e.g. lack of disk space, you might see an error during the installation, but at least then you'll find out the root cause):

```
pip uninstall pandas
pip install pandas
```

Comment: Thanks, not sure why mine suddenly stopped working between yesterday and today, but this fixed my problem.

Answer (score 0):

I faced a similar situation, and discovered that there was duplicate modules in the different site-packages folders. The problem was resolved when I copy-pasted the latest `pandas` and `pandas-1.3.1.dist-info` folders into my `AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages` folder.

One thing I noticed is that the pandas folders might be named as ~andas, so I also renamed them before copy-pasting over.

Note: I did the above because pip uninstall and install pandas did not work for me